# Error - a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp.net page with the following code -

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-next" 
        style="margin-right: 314px;" 
        onclick ="FirstDataCapture">Next</button>

function FirstDataCapture()
{
   Session["valu"] = firstName;
}
```

and when i am trying to access this value from c# code - 
        string Text = Session["valu"].ToString();

It is showing the following error - 
a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The definition of `FirstDataCapture` method seems to be erroneous. There is no c# definition which starts with `function`

A correct version might be like this.

```
void FirstDataCapture() {
    Session["valu"] = firstName;
}
```